# Vue.js Grid Component Example поменять названия колонок

Tags: vue.js

Есть официальный пример [grid component](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/xkkbfL3L/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=xkkbfL3L)

Название колонок там формируется так:

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
      { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
      { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 }
    ]
  }
})
```

Можно ли изменить название колонок и не поломать функционал (сортировка, поиск)?

Например name на Имя и power на Мощность

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например [так](https://jsfiddle.net/gw04qau2/)

В

```
data() { 
    return {

    }
}
```

Добавляем новый объект `translate` и заполняем его переводами. Затем при выводе выводим не ключ (`key`), а наш `translate` по ключу (`translate[key]`)

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста